# Symbolic summation MATLAB

Tags: matlab

Can someone help me generate the following symbolic summation in MATLAB? 
I then want to differentiate the Jacobian matrix.

$f(x) = \sum_{i=1}^{n} \sum_{j=1}^n (x_i (\Sigma x)_i - x_j (\Sigma x)_j)^2$

where $\Sigma - n \times n$ matrix and $(\Sigma x)_i$ is the i-th row of the product.

To start with,

lets say I want to generate the sum of x1+x2+x3.

I can generate x1,x2,x3 using `X = sym('x',[3 1]).`
Then, I would expect this to work: `symsum(X(k),k,1,3)`. 
But i get the following error: `Indexing input must be numeric, logical or ':'.`

how can I make this work ?

Comment: What does $(\sum x)_i$ mean?

Comment: the i-th row of the product

Comment: Is there a reason you're trying to do this symbolically? While the symbolic toolbox avails you this option, it is not the best way to use MATLAB.

Comment: I want to obtain the jacobian, and n can be different each time.

Comment: The $i$th row of what product?

Comment: the i-th row of the product of the matrix $\Sigma$ with vector x. $\Sigma$ - is a $n \times n$ matrix.

Comment: @Arkamis, the OP is trying to write the sum symbolically and differentiate symbolically.